# Continuous function, prove that $\int_0^1 x^2f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{3}f(\xi)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Suppose that $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on the interval $[0,1]$. Show that
>   $$\int_0^1x^2f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{3}f(\xi)$$
>   for some $\xi\in[0,1]$.

I guess that MVT is involved, but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Extreme Value Theorem and Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The second mean value theorem for integrals states that

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = f(c)\int_a^b g(x)dx $$
For some $c \in (a,b)$

Apply this theorem with $f(x) = f(x)$ and $g(x) = x^2$

Comment: There is no need to clarify that $f(x)=f(x)$. =)

Answer (score 2):

$f $ is continuous at $[0,1]$
$$ \implies $$

$$\exists m,M \in \mathbb R \;: \;\;f ([0,1])=[m,M] $$
$$\implies $$
$$\forall x\in [0,1]\;\;mx^2\leq x^2f (x)\leq Mx^2$$ 
$$\implies $$

$$\frac {m}{3}\leq \int_0^1x^2f (x)dx\leq \frac {M}{3} $$
(because $\int_0^1x^2dx=\frac {1}{3} $.)

$$\implies $$

$$m\leq 3\int_0^1x^2f (x)dx\leq M $$

$$\implies $$

$$\exists \xi \in [0,1]\;\;:\; 3\int_0^1x^2f (x)dx=f (\xi) $$
you can finish.

Comment: For this to work, $m$ and $M$ cannot be arbitrary bounds for $f$, but its infimum and supremum.

Comment: Any upper bound that is not the supremum is larger by definition (and similar argument for infimum with 'smaller'). The intermediate value theorem can be applied just as well in that case, it just changes the interval over which there is a solution (which is, of course, still on [0,1])